# responsive columns in flex container

Tags: angular, css, flexbox

I have a parent component which is a container

```
  <search-all-query search-query = "cr.searchQuery"  cities ="cr.cities" priorities= "cr.priorities" city ="cr.city"></search-all-query>
```

Which contains 3 child components

```
    <child-one cities = "sqc.cities" search-query = "sqc.searchQuery" city = "sqc.city"></child-one>
    <child1-two search-query = "sqc.searchQuery" priorities = "sqc.priorities"></child1l-two>
    <child1-three></child1-three>
```

I am displaying all 3child container inside flex box. I want it to be responsive in such a way any of the above boxes can expand upto 100% width of parent container. if all 3 visible then width should be 33% each if 2 visible then 50% like wise.

css-

```
 .child-1,
 .child-2,
 .child-3 {
            width: 597px;
            height: 280px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin: 0 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
            padding-top: 14px;
            padding-right: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following example. If you use `display: flex;` and set the children to `flex: 1 0 33%;` it should work as requested.

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
}

/* just for visualization */
.child {margin-bottom: 1rem; text-align: center;}
.child:first-child{ background-color: lightblue; }
.child:last-child{ background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change child element width to 100%.

`width: 100%;`